# Problems with Static Variables from Different a Class

Tags: java, string, class

I'm still working on that text adventure game, and I need help with static variables.  I have a second file in repl.it named Safe.java and it has essential code for my puzzles.  The problem is that the non-static methods, toString & findSum, cannot be referenced from a static context.

## Problem #1: toString

```
if(gotPaper == true)
{
     System.out.println("The paper has 4 numbers.  The numbers in order is:  " + Safe.toString());
}
```

## Problem #2 and #3:  findSum

```
  public static int keypad()
  {
  Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

  if(keypadOpen == true)
    {
     System.out.println("The keypad calmy tells you, \"Thank you for entering the correct number.  I have nothing more for you.\"");
    }
    else
    {
        int humanSum;
        System.out.print("The keypad yells at you, \"Enter the sum of all 4 numbers!\"");
      humanSum = key.nextInt();
      if(humanSum == Safe.findSum())
      {
        keypadOpen = true;
        System.out.println("The keypad calmy tells you, \"Thank you for entering the correct number.\"  One of the door's locks are undone.");
      }
      else if(humanSum != Safe.findSum())
      {
       System.out.println("The keypad yells at you, \"ERROR:  Entered value is incorrect!\"");
        System.out.print("You sulk to the door, defeated.");
        x++;
      }
```

## findSum and toString in Safe.java

```
    public int findSum() 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < code.length; i++)
    {
    sum += code[i];
    }
    return sum;
}


public String toString()
{
    String written;
    written = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length - 1; i++)
    {
        written = written + (code[i]+", ");
    }
    written = written + (code[code.length - 1]+"]");
    return written;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static object from `Safe`

```
static Safe safeObj = new Safe();
```

, And use `findSum` and `toString()` from the object

```
safeObj.findSum();
```